# Find the counter example that if {$f(x_n)$} is cauchy then {$f(x_n)$} is not always convergent in $Y$.

Tags: real-analysis

It is given that$ f :X \rightarrow Y$  be  a function from metric space $X$ to another metric space Y . For any cauchy sequence {$x_n$} in $X, $ Find  the counter example that
if {$f(x_n)$}  is cauchy then  {$f(x_n)$}  is  not always  convergent in $Y$.

My attempt :  i know  that  if $f(x_n)$ is cauchy  in Y then  f is  continious As 
 here  i can not able  to find out  the conterexample  to satisfied  the above satements....

Pliz help me  or give  me  any hints/solution

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}-0$ and $x_n=1/n, f=id$.

Comment: im not getting as X=  R - 0  and what is  Y ??

Comment: it is also the same set$ R-0$

Comment: $f(x_n)  = \frac {1}{n}$ ..How  it is not  convergent in Y ?? can u elaborate more ??

Comment: because $0$ is not in $R-0$.

Comment: thanks a lots@Tsemo